# Explicit specialization of a function template for a fully specialized class template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to specialize a function within a specialization of a class template, but can't figure the right syntax:

```
template< typename T >
struct Foo {};

template<>
struct Foo< int >
{
  template< typename T >
  void fn();
};

template<> template<>
void Foo< int >::fn< char >() {} // error: too many template-parameter-lists
```

Here I'm trying to specialize `fn` for `char`, which is inside of `Foo` specialized for `int`. But the compiler doesn't like what I write. What should be the right syntax then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to say that you're specializing twice.

You're only specializing *one* function template here

```
template<> void Foo<int>::fn<char>() {}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80f5ce75f37789e4)</kbd>**

```
template< typename T >
struct Foo {};

template<>
struct Foo< int >
{
  template< typename T >
  void fn();
};

template<> void Foo<int>::fn<char>() {}

int main() {
    Foo<int> f;
    f.fn<char>();
}
```

Comment: Amazingly, the compiler's error message was spot on.